# Does the axiom imply its dual?

Tags: projective-geometry

Suppose we have the following axiom for the projective plane:

> **Axiom**: If a projectivity leaves invariant each of three distinct points on a line, it leaves invariant every point of the line.

The *dual* of this axiom is the following statement:

> **Dual**: If a projectivity leaves invariant each of three distinct lines, which are concurrent at a point, it leaves invariant every line passing through that point.

Now I need to prove that **Axiom** $\Rightarrow$ **Dual**.

*My wrong attempt at the proof*: Let the three lines $a,b,c$, concurent at $O$ be the lines left invariant by the projectivity, and $l$ be any other line through $O$. If we can prove that three points on $l$ are left invariant by this projectivity, then we will have that all the points on $l$ are left invariant by the projectivity, which would imply that $l$ itself is left invariant, and we will be done, because we have taken any arbitrary line through $O$.

Now we know that $O$ is left invariant by the projectivity. For any other point, say $P$, on $l$, let a line passing through $P$ other than $l$, intersect $a, b$ and $c$ at the points $A,B$ and $C$, respectively. Now if $A,B,C$ are left invariant by the projectivity, then $P$, a point on the line $AB$, will also be left invariant. Since $P$ is any arbitrary point on $l$, this is true for all points on $l$ and we are done.

However **the lines $a,b,c$ being invariant does not imply that the points $A,B,C$ will be left invariant by the projectivity**. That is where I am stuck.

[image]

Please share any insight to nudge me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of a projectivity as an alternating sequence of points and lines and the sequences of perspectivities they represent. For a simple example, $(\ell_1,P_2,\ell_3)$ represents the perspectivity between lines $\ell_1$ and $\ell_3$ with center $P_2$.  And ($P_2,\ell_3,P_4$) is the perspectivity with axis $\ell_3$ between pencils at $P_2$ and $P_4$. ($\ell_1,P_2,\ell_3,P_4,\ell_5$) is a projectivity $\ell_1\rightarrow\ell_5$ that is the composition of two perspectivities $\ell_1\rightarrow\ell_3\rightarrow\ell_5.$

Let $(P_1,\ell_2,\dots,P_1)$ be a projectivity that leaves three lines in the pencil at $P_1$ invariant, but not the entire pencil.  Then consider $(\ell_2,\dots,P_1,\ell_2)$.  This is possibly already more than the nudge you've requested, but I'll leave the final step as a spoiler.

> $(\ell_2,\dots,P_1,\ell_2)$ is a projectivity that violates the Axiom.

Comment: This is a nice solution, I was almost there, I knew I was not using any characteristic of a projectivity. Thank you

Comment: I am stuck at this problem too : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3837065/when-is-prespectivity-of-triangles-transitive. Can you check it out

Comment: @QED, If I get a chance I'll take a look.